# What are alternatives to storing variables in Application class?

Tags: android, global-variables

While its commonly not recommended to use a class that extends `Application`, what are alternatives to store variables that are required to be accessed globally across threads?

SharedPreferences are out of choice as its physical storage and frequent access to it makes performance problems

Example case: A shopping app that holds int value in Application class about last viewed product. That variable is used in view recycler onBindViewHolder method so it cant be accessed using SharedPreferences as it would case screen freezes while scrolling

The only way I know for now is to pass it in constructor parameter which is decent because it can lead to very strange constructor parameters, or by intent which is not always viable solution (hello adapters)

Comment: what kind of information are you saving? lists of data? why is shared pref not ideal?

Comment: _"While its commonly not recommended to use a class that extends Application"_ what is this statement based on?

Comment: Because Android is "smart" and he can release the data from Application class once device resources will be low. There is more https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Understanding-the-Android-Application-Class

Comment: Android never _"releases data from Application class once device resources are low"_. It kills the whole Linux process along with the Application class. In this case you should consider permanent storage, e.g. SharedPrefs.

Answer (score 4):

> what are alternatives to store variables that are required to be accessed globally across threads?

- `static` fields, preferably as singletons
- dependency-injected singletons (e.g., Dagger 2, Koin)

> While its commonly not recommended to use a class that extends Application

Using an `Application` subclass solely to store global data is pointless — singletons are better choices. Custom `Application` subclasses are fine for per-process initialization, such as setting up the dependency injection framework, hooking up crash logging, etc.